# scanf(), field width, inf and nan

Tags: c, parsing, floating-point, language-lawyer, scanf

Per the C standard from 1999, `scanf()` and `strtod()` should accept infinity and NaN as inputs (if supported by the implementation).

The descriptions of both functions have peculiar language, which may be open to interpretations.

`scanf()`:

> An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters
>   which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a
>   prefix of, a matching input sequence.

`strtod()`:

> The subject sequence is defined as the longest initial subsequence of
>   the input string, starting with the first non-white-space character,
>   that is of the expected form.

While the latter excerpt appears to be strict in requiring the specific forms of "INF", "INFINITY", "NAN" or "NAN(n-char-sequence-opt)", the former isn't and one would think that the following code should produce infinity and NaN because the field width covers prefixes of matching input sequences:

```
int r;
double d;
d = 0; r = sscanf("inf", "%2le", &d);
printf("%d %e\n", r, d);
d = 0; r = sscanf("nan", "%2le", &d);
printf("%d %e\n", r, d);
```

There's also this bit on `scanf()`:

> a,e,f,g Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity,
>   or NaN, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence
>   of the strtod function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer
>   to floating.

Is this simply a failure to document that a field width of 2, which is shorter than the expected shortest forms ("inf" or "nan"), does not make the otherwise matching prefixes "in" and "na" valid matches?

Comment: @Shark You don't seem to understand the question.

Comment: Care to explain the -1?

Comment: very well, perhaps i do not.

Answer (score 4):

In the specification of the behaviour of `scanf`, an "input item" is precisely the sequence of input characters​ consumed by the processing of a format specifier. After processing of the format specifier, whether that processing succeeds or not, the stream is positioned precisely after the last character in the input item, as is made clear by the sentence immediately following​ the definition of "input item" quoted in the question.

> The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread.

Once the input item has been read, `scanf` proceeds to the next step (paragraph 10 of the same clause), in which the input item *as a whole* must be convertible according to the format specifier:

> 10 …[the input item] is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure.

"Matching sequence" is defined in the description of each format specifier; for a `f` specifier that will be:

> the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtod` function.

as quoted in the question.

This is not the same algorithm as used by `strtod`. `strtod` finds the longest possible matching sequence, and provided there is one (even if only one character), it converts it and places the address of the next character in the supplied `endptr` argument.

By contrast, `scanf` has to deal with the limitations of an input stream, which does not allow reliable rewinding of the read pointer by more than one character. (See the definition of `ungetc`.) So `scanf` reads until it finds a character which could not extend the match, at which point it replaces that character into the input stream and attempts to convert what has been read to that point. Unlike `strtod`, it cannot backtrack to a shorter valid sequence, if there is one.

The other difference with `strtod` is that `scanf` can be restricted to a maximum length, useful for converting undelimited fixed-length input fields. With `strtod` it would be necessary to make a NUL-terminated copy of the fixed-length field, or temporarily insert a NUL at an appropriate point and later restore the overwritten character. In such a case, it would be important to verify that `strtod` consumed the entire input; if it did not, that would indicate garbage in the input.

The difference <s>can be seen</s> may be visible empirically. Given the input `1E-@`, `scanf` <s>will</s> should report a matching failure and a subsequent `getchar` <s>will</s> should return `'@'`. `strtod` will return `1.0` with `endptr` pointing at `E`.

A specified format length can also cause `scanf` to return a matching error. Given input `1E-7@`, `scanf` formats `%2f` and `%3f` <s>will</s> should; `%1f` will convert `1.0` and `%4f` (or larger) will convert `.01`, leaving `@` for the next specifier (or subsequent input function). `%2f` applied to an input of `inf` or `nan` should exhibit precisely the same behaviour as `1E-7`: a matching failure after absorbing two characters (because the truncated field is not a valid floating point number).

Whether the above happens or not depends on whether the implementation of the standard C library conforms with the standard. Glibc does not, and glibc is most probably what you will be using on a Linux platform regardless of whether you compile with gcc or clang, because clang does not bundle a standard C library, not even in the libcxx project.

The limited testing I was able to do on Windows (using an online compiler) suggests that the libcrt implementation of scanf does work as I would expect. My own examination of the source code for the FreeBSD library suggests that it's `scanf` will correctly report matching failures but may back the read cursor up by more than one character.

Comment: "Given the input `1E-@`, `scanf` will report a matching failure and a subsequent `getchar` will return `'@'`."-- Not sure I am following you here; with, e.g., `sscanf("1E-@", "%le", &val);`, `sscanf()` will report 1 successful assignment, `val` will hold a value of `1.0`, and the next character in the input stream is `'@'`.

Comment: @david: i think that is not a conformant standard library. When I get back home if  the power failure is over I'll do some experimenting and respond more thoroughly.

Comment: I tried this on gcc and got a return value of `1`, with `val` assigned `1.0`. [Here is an Ideone link](http://ideone.com/KVR6A1) to the same code compiled with Clang and giving the same results. Just a little supporting evidence. The `scanf()` functions seem to have some dark corners; I had not noticed this particular one until today.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Clang doesn't come with its own libc, so if you install clang on linux you will end up using glibc. And glibc's scanf implementation is known to have some bugs (for example, the one where `scanf("%lf",&v)` on input "nope" fails to ungetc the `o` so that `p` is the next character in the input stream.) FreeBSD's libc implementation did more than one ungetc, the last time I tried it, so it also can produce non-standard results. I'll see if I can find a recent BSD libc implementation to test, and then update the answer. (But I claim the answer is correct according to the standard.)

Comment: @DavidBowling: one relevant bug report, complete with a classic UlrichDrepperism: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12701

Comment: I am entirely convinced that you are right about this. After looking closely at the relevant parts of the Standard, I was inclined to agree; the Standard seems pretty clear here, but maybe not quite obvious. Thanks for the link to the bug report. That seemed to close the case for me (Mr Drepper's remarks notwithstanding). Appreciate the discussion; I learned something here, and if I could upvote again I would :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to document this specific case because it's covered already in one of your quotes from the standard:

> An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters
>   which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a
>   prefix of, a matching input sequence.

Consider this simple case:

```
int ch;
int res;
const char *input_fmt;

ch = 0;
input_fmt = "%*d%c";
res = sscanf("123456789012345678901234567890abc", input_fmt, &ch);
printf("%d\t%c\n", res, ch);

// 1      a
```

Because there is no field width for the `%d` conversion specification, it will match infinitely many characters 0-9, which is why `ch=='a'` after scanning is finished; the value of `n` is unimportant here. Contrast that with the output using `input_fmt="%*2d%c"`:

```
1      3
```

The field width for the first conversion specification was limited to 2 characters, resulting in `%c` matching `3`. This is where the "prefix" bit comes in. `12` is a prefix of `123456...`, which would match the `%d` conversion specification. Another example:

```
input_fmt = "%*2d%c";
res = sscanf("1a3456789012345678901234567890bc", input_fmt, &ch);
printf("%d\t%c\n", res, ch);

// 1      a
```

The field width limited the number of characters matching `%d` to 2, but the matching input sequence had length 1 since `a` isn't a decimal integer.

The field width limiting matched input is what's going on with `inf` and `nan` in your case:

```
double d;
int r;
char s[10];

// 0       0.000000        ""
*s = 0; d = 0; r = sscanf("infinity", "%2le%9s", &d, s);
printf("%d\t%f\t\"%s\"\n", r, d, s);

// 2       inf             "inity"
*s = 0; d = 0; r = sscanf("infinity", "%3le%9s", &d, s);
printf("%d\t%f\t\"%s\"\n", r, d, s);

// 0       0.000000        ""
*s = 0; d = 0; r = sscanf("-infinity", "%3le%9s", &d, s);
printf("%d\t%f\t\"%s\"\n", r, d, s);

// 2       -inf             "inity"
*s = 0; d = 0; r = sscanf("-infinity", "%4le%9s", &d, s);
printf("%d\t%f\t\"%s\"\n", r, d, s);
```

The field width limits the number of characters in the input sequence, which may potentially prevent special forms like `-inf` and `nan` from being recognized. The behavior is documented, but it's also not immediately able to be fully understood.